# react rc-slider sensitivity for big range values

Tags: reactjs, user-experience, rc-slider

I am working with **rc-Slider** with quite a big range *(min=0, max=300.000)*. All works completely fine, but I am having an issue on mobile as it is almost impossible to set the exact desired value with the slide because the sensitivity of it is apparently too high for human fingers.

Does anyone know how to solve this problem? Are out there any other possibilities (besides typing the value in an input)?

This is the slider I got so far. The marks helped a bit, but not quite as none of the users who tested it saw that clicking on the marks positions the value to the value of that mark.

```
<Slider
  label="Einmalbeitrag"
  max={300000}
  min={0}
  unit="Euro"
  type="initial"
  step={250}
  className="initial margin-bottom"
  defaultValue={initSliders.initial}
  marks={{
    1250: '1,25T.',
    25000: '25T.',
    50000: '50T.',
    100000: '100T.',
    150000: '150T.',
    250000: '250T.',
  }}
/>
```

I appreciate if someone had any thought about this. Thanks!

Comment: I think such a large range isn't a best experience on mobiles. Maybe on desktop, you can continue using this one but for mobiles you need something else to do the job.

Comment: Check these: [Using buttons](https://ux.stackexchange.com/a/46367/91910), [Spinner](https://ux.stackexchange.com/a/91772/91910) and [Circular slider](https://ux.stackexchange.com/a/56894/91910)

Comment: Hi Ajeet, yes, I will definetily use one of the options you mention. I love the circular slider ;-) Thanks a lot!

Comment: Also, you can [self answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) this question if you come up with a good solution.